# Local const reference vs class member const reference

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference

Consider the code snippets

```
Foo FuncBar()
{
    return Foo();
}

// some where else
const Foo &myFoo = FuncBar();
```

Here the life of temporary object `Foo()` in function `FuncBar()` is extended by reference to a const `myFoo`.
Now in the below code snippet

```
class Sandbox
{
public:
    Sandbox(const string& n) : member(n) {}
    const string& member;
};

int main()
{
    Sandbox sandbox(string("four"));
    cout << "The answer is: " << sandbox.member << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here life of string "four" wasn't prolonged by using reference to const `n`. Why wasn't it prolonged?
I have checked a few of links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741147/assign-return-value-from-function-to-a-reference-c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary). Still not clear about this.

Comment: From the accepted answer to the second post you linked to: *Only local const references prolong the lifespan.*. `member` is not a local `const` reference.